# Asymptotic behaviour of an integral involving error function

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I have the following parametric integral

$$F(a)=\int_0^a e^{-x^2\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx$$

where $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ is the error function.

I'm interested in asymptotic behaviour of this integral for the cases $a\to 0$ and $a\to \infty$.

Could someone clarify to me how to obtain an asymptotic expansion of $F(a)$ ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For $a\to 0$, just expand the integrand into a Maclaurin series and integrate term-by-term: $$
F(a)=a - \frac{1}{{2\sqrt \pi  }}a^4  + \frac{1}{{9\sqrt \pi  }}a^6  + \frac{2}{{7\pi }}a^7  +  \ldots \,.
$$

Comment: For $a\to +\infty$, you can use $$ 
F(a)  \sim \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - x^2 \operatorname{erf}(x)} dx}  - \frac{{e^{ - a^2 \operatorname{erf}(a)} }}{{2a}}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2a^2 }} + \frac{3}{{4a^4 }} +  \ldots } \right).
$$ The value of the definite integral on the right-hand side is $0.9721069927691785931\ldots$.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 2):

For the case where $a$ is small, you can approximate
$$e^{-x^2 \text{erf}(x)}$$ by a simple $[n,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ built around $x=0$. For example
$$P_3=\frac{1+\frac 13 x^2 -\frac 1 {\sqrt \pi}x^3}{1+\frac 13 x^2 +\frac 1 {\sqrt \pi}x^3 }$$ whose error is $\frac {x^7} {45\sqrt \pi}$ which is easy to integrate using partial fraction decomposition; the denominator has only one real root and we shall face one logarithm and an arctangent.

For example, for $a=0.5$, numerical integration gives $0.48390392$ while the approximation of the integrand by $P_3$ gives $0.48389086$.